# How to create a gif from a list of AxesSubplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, data-science, geopandas

I have a list of AxesSubplots that I created using the plot function in GeoPandas. I want to generate a gif from it using the animation library. From what I understand, the FuncAnimation requires a matrix on its update function. Is there a way to use my AxesSubplots, which already contain a plot, along with the FuncAnimation function?